# Declaring string and condition in vb

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a String variable in this page named "a".
I wanted the scenario to be.

When the page is started "a" will be null.

But when the user selected an entry from the DetailView Control "a" will become "have".

The following is my code. But i keep getting "a" = null even though i have selected an entry from the detailView control.

```
Dim a As String

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
End Sub

Protected Sub GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged
    a = "a"
End Sub
```

Why is this so? How should i go about doing it?

Answer (score 3):

When ever you do any operation on you page with server side controls and your page postback, all the variables which are declared globally are again reset and go at their initial stage, so that's why you are getting a = null every time.

Comment: I see. Then how should i go about doing it?

Answer (score 2):

The code is ok, but you are changing the value when the selected index changes on a gridview, not a detailsview, also values are not stored through postbacks. If you assign the gridview selected value to a label for example, and viewstate is active, then it will be maintained on that control. But variables on the VB are reset on each postback.

Anyway for doing that you can update the string on the Page_Load

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load       
    a = "a" 'or whatever value you need. i.e. the gridview selected data key, etc...
End Sub
```

Or if its based on what the user does, add the page.ispostback

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load  
    If Page.IsPostBack Then     
        a = "a" 'or whatever value you need. i.e. the gridview selected data key, etc...
        'or for example...
        a = Me.aDropDown.SelectedItem.Text
    Else
        a = String.Empty
    End If
End Sub
```

If not, "a" will allways be equal to string.empty each time the page loads.